# write special data to Mifare IC card with ZKteco time attendance device

Tags: c#, zkteco

I'm a programmer and I'm developing a software for my client who wants to control his club devices for his customers.
Can I write certain information (for example a special number ) on a particular part of the IC card by my time attendance device? (when each customer holds the end of his / her card in front of the device)?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can´t do it using a ZKTeco time and attendance device... I´m afraid that you will need something different to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use USB Card Reader/Writer for writing the details on the card. Time attendance devices will read the card and check with what is stored in its internal database and record attendance on successful matching.